# How to unbind() a hover/ mouseover event?

Tags: jquery, css, bind, unbind

My idea is very simple. I have a menu bar made from an unordered list of 3 items. Each item has an image coinciding with the title. I Photoshop'ed an 'active' version of each icon. Every time the list-item is hovered on, I wanted the src of the img to change to the 'active' icon. But I also want the 'active' icon to stay once clicked on.

I have a general idea of how it's supposed to be written, but I've never used bind() or unbind() before

I want to know the proper way to write the following:

```
function nav_handler() {
    $(".nav_services").hover(function() {
        var src = $(".nav_services img").attr("src", "files/img/services2.png");
        $(".nav_services").mousedown(function() {
            $(this).unbind(hover);
        });
    }, function() {
        var src = $(".nav_services img").attr("src", "files/img/services.png");
    });
};
```

I don't think any of the HTML or CSS is necessary for this question, but I'll post it if you need it. This was an example of 1 of the 3 classes (list items), so I don't know if you can do it using it's parent and using children() and change the icon based on the return value of which child was hovered on or clicked on, but that would be even more helpful.

---

**UPDATE**

Okay, so I used unbind correctly, but the src of the img in the list item will only change once. Meaning if I click all of them one at a time, the src will only change once. This is the full function I'm currently using:

```
function beta_handler() {
//Hover for Nav-item #1 (Services)
$(".nav_services").hover(function () {
    var src = $(".nav_services img").attr("src", "files/img/services2_active.png");
    $(".nav_services").mousedown(function () {
        if ($(".nav_home").hasClass("nav_active")) {
            $(".nav_home").removeClass("nav_active");
            var src = $(".nav_home img").attr("src", "files/img/home2.png")
            $(this).addClass("nav_active");
            //$(this).unbind("hover");
            $(this).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
        }
        else if ($(".nav_contact").hasClass("nav_active")) {
            $(".nav_contact").removeClass("nav_active");
            var src = $(".nav_contact img").attr("src", "files/img/contact2.png")
            $(this).addClass("nav_active");
            //$(this).unbind("hover");
            $(this).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
        }
    });
}, function () {
    var src = $(".nav_services img").attr("src", "files/img/services2.png");
});
//Hover for Nav-item #2 (Home)
$(".nav_home").hover(function () {
    var src = $(".nav_home img").attr("src", "files/img/home2_active.png");
    $(".nav_home").mousedown(function () {
        if ($(".nav_services").hasClass("nav_active")) {
            $(".nav_services").removeClass("nav_active");
            var src = $(".nav_services img").attr("src", "files/img/services2.png")
            $(this).addClass("nav_active");
            //$(this).unbind("hover");
            $(this).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
        }
        else if ($(".nav_contact").hasClass("nav_active")) {
            $(".nav_contact").removeClass("nav_active");
            var src = $(".nav_contact img").attr("src", "files/img/contact2.png")
            $(this).addClass("nav_active");
            //$(this).unbind("hover");
            $(this).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
        }
    });
}, function () {
    var src = $(".nav_home img").attr("src", "files/img/home2.png");
});
//Hover for Nav-item #3 (Contact)
$(".nav_contact").hover(function () {
    var src = $(".nav_contact img").attr("src", "files/img/contact2_active.png");
    $(".nav_contact").mousedown(function () {
        if ($(".nav_services").hasClass("nav_active")) {
            $(".nav_services").removeClass("nav_active");
            var src = $(".nav_services img").attr("src", "files/img/services2.png")
            $(this).addClass("nav_active");
            //$(this).unbind("hover");
            $(this).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
        }
        else if ($(".nav_home").hasClass("nav_active")) {
            $(".nav_home").removeClass("nav_active");
            var src = $(".nav_home img").attr("src", "files/img/home2.png")
            $(this).addClass("nav_active");
            //$(this).unbind("hover");
            $(this).unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
        }
    });
}, function () {
    var src = $(".nav_contact img").attr("src", "files/img/contact2.png");
});
};
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pex42rk0/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `hover` function is actually a shortcut method. It binds `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. To remove the binding you'll need to unbind both events ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ktmkfscL/)):

```
$('button').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('red');
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('red');
}).click(function(){
    $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
});
```

---

Update: Everything you are trying to do can be done using CSS only ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/pex42rk0/1/)) - no need to complicate things with javascript/jQuery.

HTML

```
<div id="nav_container">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav_services"><i></i>SERVICES</li>
        <li class="nav_home nav_active"><i></i>HOME</li>
        <li class="nav_contact"><i></i>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav_container li {
    background: #fff;
    border-color: #b6b5ba;
}
#nav_container li:hover {
    background: #dfdeff;
}
#nav_container li.nav_active {
    background-color: #cecdf6;
}
#nav_container i {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.nav_services i {
    background-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-cog-outline-128.png);
}
.nav_services.nav_active i, .nav_services:hover i {
    background-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-cog-128.png);
}
.nav_home i {
    background-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-contact-outline-128.png);
}
.nav_home.nav_active i, .nav_home:hover i {
    background-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-contact-128.png);
}
.nav_contact i {
    background-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-telephone-outline-128.png);
}
.nav_contact.nav_active i, .nav_contact:hover i {
    background-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-telephone-128.png);
}
#nav_container {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 20px 0 0 15%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px #b6b5ba solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
#nav_container ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#nav_container li {
    font-family: Calibri, Verdana;
    display: table-cell;
    line-height: 40px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.nav_services {
    border-right: 1px #dedede solid;
}
.nav_home {
    border-left: 1px #dedede solid;
    border-right: 1px #dedede solid;
}
.nav_contact {
    border-left: 1px #dedede solid;
}
```

---

Update 2: I wasn't sure how your tab system worked, but you would need some scripting to add or remove the `nav_active` class name:

```
$(function () {
    $('#nav_container li').click(function () {
        $(this)
            .addClass('nav_active')
            .siblings()
            .removeClass('nav_active');
    });
});
```

Comment: I altered my code to unbinding both mouseenter and mouseleave, and every time I hover after I've clicked all three list-item images, they no longer change on hover or on click as I stated in the update.

Comment: Does the click function have to be outside of the hover function?

Comment: That's a lot of code to sort through... it would be easier, and quicker for us to answer if you provided a demo of the problem. And yes, the `click` must be separate.

Comment: I'll test the code with the click seperate and let you know. If it doesn't work, I'll provide a demo.

Comment: you got the hover effect working, which I can do on my own. But notice if you click each list item that isn't highlighted nothing happens?

Comment: I removed the `:active` definition, you can add it back. And to make a item active, add or remove the `nav_active` class name. I was guessing you had tabs set up to work with that?

Answer (score 0):

Unbind method should be called this way (passing event name as string):

```js
$(this).unbind("hover");
```

For more examples read the manual: [.unbind()](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)

Comment: This solved my initial problem. Thank you, I will designate your answer as the correct one.

BUT would you check the update please? Tell me what I'm doing wrong if you can?

Comment: You can't `unbind()` a hover. Please see my answer.